# TSQL - combining two virtual tables with left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, outer-join

I need some help.

I have a table called @combine

Here are the results of it

[image]

I have the table @monthofyear and the DRAW table I want (see image 2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBefh.png)

I want to do a query that will give me this DRAW table, so I can draw a chart in SSRS

I red many forums saying that I have to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN between tables to active the DRAW table.

Here is my code:

```
select ss.Phil
    ,ss.amounttype
    ,m.months
    ,ss.allmount
from @monthofyear as m
left outer join (
    select c.phil
        ,c.amounttype
        ,c.month_name
        ,sum(COALESCE(c.amount, 0)) as allmount
    from @combine as c
    group by phil
        ,amounttype
        ,month_name
    ) ss on (m.months = ss.month_name)
where ss.phil = 'F-14-0023'
group by ss.phil
    ,ss.amounttype
    ,m.months
    ,ss.allmount
```

It is not giving me the DRAW table layout. Can some one please help me?

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
Phil    amounttype  months  allmount
F-14-0023   ACTUAL  February    594.46
F-14-0023   ACTUAL  January 7019.23
F-14-0023   BUDGET  April   1340.00
F-14-0023   BUDGET  December    282500.00
F-14-0023   BUDGET  February    1340.00
F-14-0023   BUDGET  January 1340.00
F-14-0023   BUDGET  July    -282647.00
F-14-0023   BUDGET  March   1340.00
F-14-0023   FORECAST    March   1303.36
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Phil    amounttype  months  allmount
F-14-23 ACTUAL  Feb 594.46
F-14-23 ACTUAL  Jan 7019.23
F-14-23 ACTUAL  Mar 0
F-14-23 ACTUAL  Apr 0
F-14-23 ACTUAL  May 0
F-14-23 ACTUAL  June    0
F-14-23 ACTUAL  July    0
        (until December)    
F-14-23 BUDGET  Apr 1340
F-14-23 BUDGET  Dec 282500
F-14-23 BUDGET  Feb 1340
F-14-23 BUDGET  Jan 1340
F-14-23 BUDGET  July    -282647
F-14-23 BUDGET  Mar 1340
F-14-23 BUDGET  Jan 0
F-14-23 BUDGET  May 0
F-14-23 BUDGET  June    0
        (all other months)  
F-14-23 FORECAST    Mar 130.36
        (all other months)
```

**OUTPUT with ALAN's code****

```
 Phil   amounttype  monthsname  AllAmount
 Phil   amounttype  monthsname  AllAmount
  NULL  NULL    August  0
  NULL  NULL    June    0
  NULL  NULL    May 0
  NULL  NULL    November    0
  NULL  NULL    October 0
  NULL  NULL    September   0
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  April   1340
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  December    282500
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  February    1340
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  January 1340
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  July    -282647
  F-14-0023 BUDGET  March   1340
```

code here

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What you mean `is not giving me the DRAW table layout.`? what is the problem?

Comment: We cant read data in comment. Edit your question to show, Current and Desire Output ... and explain what is wrong

Comment: I cant edit my question

Comment: Refresh and load again? You are the owner you can always edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a table for `month`, but you also need the `type` for each month

```
SELECT ss.Phil,
       t.amounttype,
       m.months,
       ss.allmount
FROM @monthofyear as m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT amounttype  -- CREATE ALL (month, type)
            FROM @combine) as t
LEFT JOIN (
    select 'F-14-0023' as phil,
           c.amounttype,
           c.month_name,
           sum(COALESCE(c.amount, 0)) as allmount
    from @combine as c
    WHERE ss.phil = 'F-14-0023'
    group by phil,
             amounttype,
             month_name
    ) ss 
   ON m.months = ss.month_name
  AND t.amounttype = ss.amounttype  -- Match with the above (month, type)
```

Comment: I tried your code above, getting the same result as I posted on "current Output"

Comment: First check only the `cross join` to make sure you have all combination `(month,type)`. Also remove the last `GROUP BY`

Comment: btw, dont you need `YEAR` to distinguish between `2017-01` and `2016-01` ??

Comment: before the data is brought into the @combine table, it is filtered for current year.

Comment: That error doesn't make sense. Again try each query separated. Check again with the edited answer

Comment: that error is gone, I took the wrong "group by" out. Right now I am not experiencing the error anymore.

Comment: juan, still getting the same output at "current output"

Comment: the Cross Join works great by itself, but with the select distinct nested gives the "current output"

Comment: Alan was correct, you cant use filter on the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are joining the two tables and **then** filtering the result to anything where ss.phil = 'F-14-0023'. You need to move the WHERE clause inside your inner query. Based on your original attempt it will look like this.

DECLARE @phil varchar(30) = 'F-14-0023'

```
select @phil
    , CASE WHEN ss.amounttype NOT NULL THEN ss.AmountType
      ELSE 
         CASE WHEN month_number <= month(getdate()) THEN 'ACTUAL'
         ELSE 'BUDGET'
         END
      END AS AmountType
    ,m.months
    ,ss.allmount
from @monthofyear as m
left outer join (
    select c.phil
        ,c.amounttype
        ,c.month_name
        ,sum(COALESCE(c.amount, 0)) as allmount
    from @combine as c
    WHERE c.Phil = 'F-14-0023'
    group by phil
        ,amounttype
        ,month_name
    ) ss on (m.months = ss.month_name)
group by ss.phil
    ,ss.amounttype
    ,m.months
    ,ss.allmount
```

Now what we're doing is taking your months table, LEFT JOINing it to your @Combine table AFTER we have filtered the results. You'll probably need to do something about the NULLS you will get in the AllAmount and AmountType columns (e.g. ISNULL(AllAmount, 0) AS AllAmount )

**UPDATE** Assuming that the 'F-14-0023' is passed in as a parameter, simply use this in place of the ss.Phil field in your select (on the first line)
The amounttype column woudl have to be a CASE statement based on month. You will probably need to add a month_number colume to the @monthofyear table. You can extend this to clculate if it should read forecast based on your requirements. I've updated the query above to illustrate.

There may be errors in the code as I don't have time to setup test data but it should be close enough to follow.

Comment: I got it to somewhat working. I got the extra months added and managed to get the AMOUNT field as 0. But how do I fill the phil field? it is also showing null for months added with left join.

Comment: I have posted the OUTPUT at the very end of my QUESTION up top